# how to populate lightning menu item in LWC dynamically using for:each directive?

Tags: lightning-web-components, menu

I'm trying to populate the lightning menu item in LWC with values from get method in javascript. however I'm stopped with an error

> Missing key for element  inside of iterator. Elements within iterators must have a unique, computed key value.

I'm attaching the code for reference

```
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    get menuItemValues(){
        [{label :'menu1',
        value : 'menu1'},
        {label :'menu2',
        value : 'menu2'},
        {label :'menu3',
        value : 'menu3'},
        {label :'menu4',
        value : 'menu4'},
        {label :'menu5',
        value : 'menu5'}]
    }
}

    <template>
<lightning-card title ="Demo on LWC" >
<div class="slds-m-top_large">
    <lightning-button-menu icon-name="utility:rows"
    alternative-text="Toggle menu">
    <template for:each={menuItemValues} for:item="menuvalue" >  
    <lightning-menu-item 
        label={menuvalue.label}
        value={menuvalue.value}
        >
    </lightning-menu-item>
    </template>
</lightning-button-menu>
</div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where can I add the Key attribute

Comment: Simply add the "key" attribute on the menu item, probably set using ```key={menuvalue.value}``` to ensure there's a unique value for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [developer guide](https://lwc.dev/guide/html_templates#render-lists), you must include a `key` attribute to allow the infrastructure to target changes in the UI when reacting to changes. The key value needs to be unique in the given context. In your case you should add the key to the menu item. On the assumption the menuvalue.value is unique, it can be:

```
<template for:each={menuItemValues} for:item="menuvalue" >  
    <lightning-menu-item 
        label={menuvalue.label}
        value={menuvalue.value}
        key={menuvalue.value}>
    </lightning-menu-item>
</template>
```

I would also update the component to use the following approach:

```
@track
menuItemValues =
    [{label :'menu1',
    value : 'menu1'},
    {label :'menu2',
    value : 'menu2'},
    {label :'menu3',
    value : 'menu3'},
    {label :'menu4',
    value : 'menu4'},
    {label :'menu5',
    value : 'menu5'}];
```

Having the menu item values tracked will ensure the menu updates if you change the options.

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: See the update I applied to the component JS: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/mXg0BqI1J/10/edit

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the return keyword in your JS method.

```
get menuItemValues(){
    return [{label :'menu1',
    value : 'menu1'},
    {label :'menu2',
    value : 'menu2'},
    {label :'menu3',
    value : 'menu3'},
    {label :'menu4',
    value : 'menu4'},
    {label :'menu5',
    value : 'menu5'}]
}
```

Comment: thanks that was the change I'm required to make the code work